# Counting number of unique combinations

Tags: combinatorics, programming

I came across a programming challenge recently and I'm wondering if there's a closed-form solution to this.

There is a strip with squares of unit length each. The strip's total length is N (i.e. there are N squares). You have M painters of length K units each. You can paint over the squares with these painters however many times you want. How many unique combinations can you make?

Ex. N = 3, M = 2, K = 2 gives 6 unique combinations 
(000 , 111, 011, 100, 001, 110)

I currently have a brute-force algorithm to solve this, but I'm sure there has to be a more elegant solution.

I am not a student and this is not a homework question. I just do these for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible combinations are precisely the ones containing $K$ consecutive squares of the same color.

These are the only ones possible, because the last time you paint, you create such a strip. To see that all of them are possible, we can use the following algorithm.

Suppose that we have a sequence of colors $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_N$ with $a_{i+1} = a_{i+2} = \dots = a_{i+K}$ for some $i$. Then:

1. First, make sure that colors $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_i$ are correct, in that order. To do this, color the interval $[1,K]$ with color $a_1$, then the interval $[2,K+1]$ with color $a_2$, and so on, until you color the interval $[i,i+K-1]$ with color $a_i$.
2. Second, make sure that colors $a_N, a_{N-1}, \dots, a_{i+K+1}$ are correct, in that order. To do this, color the interval $[N-K+1,N]$ with color $a_N$, then the interval $[N-K,N-1]$ with color $a_{N-1}$, and so on, until you color the interval $[i+1,i+K+1]$ with color $a_{i+K+1}$.
3. Finally, color the interval $[i+1,I+K]$ with the color that all $K$ of these squares are supposed to have.

---

This gives us a characterization of the possible combinations; counting them is a bit harder.

There is a recursive formula for *impossible* combinations. Fix $M,K$ and let $c_N$ be the number of impossible combinations of length $N$. (So, the number we actually want - the number of possible combinations - is $M^N - c_N$.) For $N=1,2,\dots,K-1$, we have $c_N = M^N$. For $N \ge K$, we have
$$
   c_N = (M-1) \left(c_{N-1} + c_{N-2} + \dots + c_{N-K+1}\right)
$$
by breaking it up into cases: some number between $1$ and $K-1$ of the rightmost squares have the same color (but no more than that many), and they have one of the $M-1$ possible colors that are not equal to the color that comes before them.

This generally doesn't have a nice closed form. Some special cases do:

- When $K=2$, we have $c_1 = M$ and $c_N = (M-1) c_{N-1}$ when $N \ge 2$, so $c_N = M(M-1)^{N-1}$.
- When $M=2$ and $K=3$, we have $c_1 = 2$, $c_2 = 4$ and $c_N = c_{N-1} + c_{N-2}$ when $N \ge 3$, which is the Fibonacci number recurrence. Here, $c_N = 2F_{N+1}$, where we take the Fibonacci numbers to begin $F_1 = 1, F_2 =1, F_3 = 2, \dots$.

Comment: Wow, interesting! Thank you. I was really hoping that there would be a more elegant or a closed-form expression because my brute-force approach for doing this is kind of slow and messy.

Comment: +1 nice answer but i think there is a minor mistake: Basically you are saying if $N < K$ then all $M^N$ patterns are impossible, right?  Then for $M=2, K=3$ we should have $c_2 = 2^2 = 4$.  So the $c_N$ are still twice the Fibonnaci numbers but maybe now the $(N+1)$th one?  Depends on how your start the Fibs.  :)

Comment: @antkam Thanks for spotting this! Fixed :)

Comment: For $M=2$ and general $K$, does the recurrence have a general solution? If $K=2$ then $c_N$ grows as $\phi^N$, and for general $K$ it would seem $c_N$ grows as $\lambda_K^N$ right? But my gut feel also tells me $\lambda_K \to 2$ for large $K$. So out of $2^N$ patterns something like $(2-\epsilon)^N$ are impossible...?

Comment: For general $K$, we're looking at generalizations like the Tribonacci numbers and so forth (which I think is what you mean?). Possibly with different initial conditions, but the largest root of the characteristic polynomial will still determine the growth.

Comment: ah, thanks for the name!  Tribonacci.  and then Tetranacci, etc. (according to wiki & OEIS).  thanks!  my other observation was simply the largest root $\lambda_K \to 2$ for large $K$, which is (in retrospect) not surprising, so nothing to see there.

Comment: Yeah, an upper bound on the number of impossible configurations is $M^N (1 - \frac1{M^{K-1}})^{N/K}$ (just by looking at $N/K$ disjoint blocks of length $K$) which is $(M-\epsilon)^N$.

Comment: So, if I were to construct an algorithm to calculate the number of unique combinations for a given (N, M, K), there is presumably no better way to solve it other than brute force?

Comment: @user34801 What? No, the recursion I gave is going to be way better than that. Even without tricks to speed up the recursion, you can find $c_N$ in just $N$ steps.

Comment: Oh okay, maybe I misunderstood your answer? I thought the recursion formula is for combinations that are not allowed, not for the number of unique combinations?

Comment: Oh! Yes, but you know the total number of combinations, it's $M^N$. So $M^N - c_N$ gives you the number you want.

Comment: Hi Misha, oh okay! Of course, I was being slow! Thanks so much :) I'm going to try implementing this method now.